# How to create multiple fusion charts on one page?

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

I have the following code which produces this:

[image]

If you look at my code, I'm actually trying to rendor 2 charts, and put them on separate table rows so they will be one on top of the other. That's why there are the table lines bunched up around the bottom of the graph. When I delete all the code for my first graph, my second graph shows up on the webpage, but if it is there it does not show up. Is there something I am missing?

I was thinking that maybe I had to include the line: `dbhandle->close` after each graph, but that wouldn't make much sense since it is just the connection to my MySQL database.

```
    <?php

      include("includes/fusioncharts.php");
      // variables declared before
      $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

       // Render an error message, to avoid abrupt failure, if the database connection parameters are incorrect
       if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
            exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
       }
    ?>

    <html>
       <head>
        <title>FusionCharts XT - Column 2D Chart - Data from a database</title>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

        <script src="fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

    <?php

        $strQuery = "SELECT Department, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Scrap GROUP BY Department ORDER BY Department";

        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result) {
                // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
                $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                    "caption" => "Scrap by Department",
                    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                    "showValues"=> "0",
                    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
                )
                );

                $arrData["data"] = array();

        // Push the data into the array

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                "label" => $row["Department"],
                "value" => $row["Quantity"],
                //"link" => "deptDrillDown.php?Department=".$row["Department"]
                )
                );
                }

        $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

        $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

        // Render the chart
        $columnChart->render();
        }

        $strQuery2 = "SELECT ScrapDate, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Scrap WHERE Department = 'NW' GROUP BY ScrapDate ORDER BY ScrapDate";

        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result2 = $dbhandle->query($strQuery2) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result2) {
                // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
                $arrData2 = array(
                "chart" => array(
                    "caption" => "By Week",
                    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                    "showValues"=> "0",
                    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
                )
                );

                $arrData2["data"] = array();

        // Push the data into the array

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                array_push($arrData2["data"], array(
                "label" => $row["ScrapDate"],
                "value" => $row["Quantity"],
                //"link" => "deptDrillDown.php?Department=".$row["Department"]
                )
                );
                }

        $jsonEncodedData2 = json_encode($arrData2);

        $columnChart2 = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-2", "json", $jsonEncodedData2);

        // Render the chart
        $columnChart2->render();

        // Close the database connection
        $dbhandle->close();

        }
?>


<table border='1'>
<tr>
        <td>
                <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>
                <div id="chart-2"><!-- Fusion Charts will also be rendered here--></div>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**SOLVED:**
I looked up the constructor for the FusionCharts object, and the 2nd parameter is a unique identifier for the chart. Since I copy and pasted before, I did not think to change it. I set it to chart 2 and now both charts render properly.

This is what it used to be:

```
$columnChart2 = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-2", "json", $jsonEncodedData2);
```

This is the updated code:

```
$columnChart2 = new FusionCharts("column2D", "mySecondChart" , 600, 300, "chart-2", "json", $jsonEncodedData2);
```

Comment: No errors at all. I tested and put an echo "hello": at the end of the second graphs code and it echoed fine so the code is being run

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen thanks, I updated the code now.